# (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (consume) on node type (GamesIAPOrder)

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Пытаюсь прикрутить [Payments Lite](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games_payments/payments_lite).

Запрос на покупку работает.

Запрос на список покупок тоже:

```
[
  {
    "purchase_token": "###",
    "product_id": "###",
    "app_id": "###",
    "purchase_time": ###,
    "payment_id": "######",
    "consumed": false,
    "signed_request": "###",
    "payment_action_type": "charge"
  }
]
```

Но если пытаюсь использоваться кпленный product с помощью метода `consume`, чтоб потом можно было снова потом купить, используя  `purchase_token`, запрос возвращает:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (consume) on node type (GamesIAPOrder)",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "CPjKLsTkf/G
"
  }
}
```

Код:

```
FB.API("/" + purchaseToken + "/consume", HttpMethod.GET, OnConsume, new Dictionary<string, string> {
     {"access_token", accessToken}
});
```

В какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно было `POST` запросом посылать...

```
FB.API("/" + purchaseToken + "/consume", HttpMethod.POST, OnConsume, new Dictionary<string, string> {
     {"access_token", accessToken}
});
```